# Extending interfaces and hover hints

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working with TypeScript in VS Code. I have three interfaces: `A`, `B` and `C`, each one with two properties. `C` extends `A` and `B`.

```
interface A {
  A1: boolean;
  A2: boolean;
}

interface B {
  B1: boolean;
  B2: boolean;
}

interface C extends A, B {
  C1: boolean;
  C2: boolean;
}

const ABC: C = {
  A1: true,
  A2: true,
  B1: true,
  B2: true,
  C1: true,
  C2: true,
};

console.log(ABC);
```

When I hover `C` I only see its own properties.

This is not convenient, as I can't see the whole interface in the codebase when I use `C` for any object.

[image]
Is this intended?

Comment: I must agree it is rather annoying that there is no option for this to show, even if it does bloat up the hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended because otherwise when extending a more sophisticated interface (like `HTMLELement`) your preview would get bloated with properties not inherently relevant to your interface. If you really need an index of all avaliable properties of `C`, just write `ABC.` (when nothing happens try Ctrl+Space). Or Ctrl+click on `C` to see its declaration and further on `A` or `B` to inspect those.